# Xodus: InvalidSettingException

Tags: xodus

When running my application outside of IntelliJ I get an `jetbrains.exodus.InvalidSettingException: Unknown DataReaderWriterProvider`:

```
jetbrains.exodus.InvalidSettingException: Unknown DataReaderWriterProvider: jetbrains.exodus.io.FileDataReaderWriterProvider
            at jetbrains.exodus.log.LogConfig.getReaderWriterProvider(LogConfig.java:312)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.kt:85)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newLogInstance(Environments.kt:73)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments$newInstance$4.invoke(Environments.kt:45)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments$newInstance$4.invoke(Environments.kt:27)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.prepare(Environments.kt:112)
            at jetbrains.exodus.env.Environments.newInstance(Environments.kt:45)
            at jetbrains.exodus.entitystore.PersistentEntityStores.newInstance(PersistentEntityStores.java:64)
```

Unfortunately, I could not find any information about that. Does anyone have an idea what's going on there?

Comment: Which xodus dependencies did you declare in your application?

Comment: @VyacheslavLukianov `libraryDependencies += "org.jetbrains.xodus" % "xodus-entity-store" % "1.3.232"`

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/XD-822